# Как использовать static_assert для следующего фрагмента кода?

Tags: c++

Есть вот такой пользовательский литерал. Я бы хотел выкинуть предупреждение в случае если принимаемое значение не лежит в диапазоне 0..7. Могу ли я этого добиться?

```
constexpr unsigned char operator"" _cmd(const char command) {
      if (command == '>')
        return 0;
      else if (command == '<')
        return 1;
      else if (command == '+')
        return 2;
      else if (command == '-')
        return 3;
      else if (command == ',')
        return 4;
      else if (command == '.')
        return 5;
      else if (command == '[')
        return 6;
      else if (command == ']')
        return 7;
       else 
       static_assert(, "INVALID COMMAND");
    }
```

Comment: `static_assert` работает во время компиляции, а реальное значение `command` может стать известным только на этапе выполнения.

Comment: @VTT да, но литерал возвращает constexpr и я полагаю работает на этапе компиляции или я ошибаюсь? Я считал что значение литерала вычисляется на этапе компиляции.

Comment: Он *может* работать на этапе, да.

Comment: @VTT как понимать, может?

Comment: `constexpr` функции могут вычисляться как в во время компиляции, так и в рантайме.

Comment: существуют constexpr if

Comment: @VTT, конкретно этот оператор может в рантайме работать? Мне кажется литералы всегда на момент компиляции известны. P.s., но да, это не говорит о том, что разработчики языка делали отдельную логику для сточных литералов и static_assert

Comment: @ДмитрийЗиненко Перегружаемые операторы всегда могут вызваться как обычные функции c аргументом, известным только на этапе выполнения. Например `char c{}; ::std::cin >> c; operator""_cmd(c);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В данном случае похоже, что натурального решения со `static_assert` нет, ибо ваша функция в общем случае совсем не обязательно вычисляется во время компиляции. Однако вы можете воспользоваться хитростью и вместо `static_assert` использовать `throw` или любую другую конструкцию, которая заведомо "убивает" constexpr-ность функции

```
...
else if (command == ']')
  return 7;
else 
  throw 0;
```

Это приведет к тому, что именно данная ветка логики функции никогда не будет константным выражением. В тех контекстах, где язык требует константного выражения, будет происходить ошибка компиляции

```
template <unsigned char C> struct S{};

int main()
{
  S<'+'_cmd>(); // OK
  S<'/'_cmd>(); // Error

  constexpr int a = ','_cmd; // OK
  constexpr int b = ':'_cmd; // Error
}
```

К сожалению, в тех контекстах, где константного выражения не требуется, ошибки компиляции не будет, а будет полноценное бросание исключения во время выполнения. То есть вам, для достижения изначальной цели (ошибки компиляции при неправильном аргументе) придется самому внимательно следить за тем, чтобы литерал использовался только в контекстах, *требующих* константного выражения.

Answer (score 0):

В с++ 14 должно работать.

```
else 
       assert(false && "INVALID COMMAND");
```

При этом, если assert сработает на этапе компиляции, она упадёт.
P.s сам не проверял, но пруф:
https://www.google.com/amp/s/akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2017/05/18/asserts-in-constexpr-functions/amp/
Там есть способ это сделать и на с++ 11